# How can I improve score of exact match in Marklogic

Tags: json, search, marklogic, marklogic-9

I have collection movie. I have movie json document containing json properties as movie name, release year etc. I am trying to search on movie name where I would like the exact word matches to score higher. For example, if I search for movie name "Star Trek" I want "Star Trek" to score highest (first result) followed by "Star Trek Beyond" and "Star Trek Into Darkness".
Currently when I search for "Star Trek" I get the movie name with additional words scoring higher.

Also is it possible that I can query on more json properties to get more accurate result.

Example
I have three documents
doc1-

```
{
  "MovieName":"Star Trek",
  "ReleaseYear":1966
}
```

doc2-

```
{
  "MovieName":"Star Trek Beyond",
  "ReleaseYear":2016
}
```

doc3-

```
{
  "MovieName":"Star Trek Into Darkness",
  "ReleaseYear":2013
}
```

if I search for movie name "Star Trek" with release year "1965" then then exact match should get higher score or near match should get higher score. so here even if 1965 doesn't match to release year of provided documents still I should get near match result.

So here I want result score wise as doc1,doc3,doc2. Similar way I should be able to provide more properties to get near accurate result.
I tried boost query but I am not getting desired results.

Answer (score 0):

What was in your boost query?  Did you use cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery or a range query to eliminate partial matches?

Comment: currently I am using jsearch. 
"TitleFullName": {
      "$or" : [
        {"$value": "Movie Name","$exact":true,"$weight":4},
        {"$word": "Movie Name"}
      ]
    }
giving more weight to exact match.
But figuring out how to improve score of closet years of reference year.
reference year=2004 then exact match should have highest score then 2003 and 2005 and so on.

Comment: OK, I see.  I'm not as familiar with jsearch.  I was thinking of https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.boostQuery.  With that you could construct what you want, even if it's a bit tedious?  With a range index on year you can score on distance from the value:

https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.rangeQuery
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/relevance#id_51643

Not sure about fitting these into jsearch.